# How to write into a currently open MS Access 2010 Database from within another MS Access 2010 Database via VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am able to connect to a remote .accdb file to write content into a table as long as the target database is not currently open, but I am forced to write into that database even while it is open. Doing copy and paste manually from database1.tableA to database2.tableA while both are open works fine. But why does VBA not get the job done? Here is what I've tried so far:

Way 1:

```
...
Dim dbTarget As Database

Set dbTarget = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("X:\path\to\file.accdb")
...
```

Error (translated from German):

```
... failed with error (3029): No valid account name or no valid password.
```

Way 2:

```
...
Dim wrkDev As Workspace
Dim dbTarget As Database

Set wrkDev = CreateWorkspace("", "Admin", "", dbUseJet)   ' adopted from microsoft docs

Set dbTarget = wrkDev.OpenDatabase("X:\path\to\file.accdb", True)
...
```

Error (translated from German):

```
... failed with error (3029): No valid account name or no valid password.
```

Why is that and how to fix?

Comment: What's the security situation on that `.accdb`? (Unsecured/encrypted/unsecured with secure linked tables/user-level security). It seems like you're trying to open an `.accdb` using a user-level security approach, while the `.accdb` format doesn't support that type of security.

Comment: Encryption is no topic in this case. Even the sys admin confirmed no specific settings on that file. How can I find out what you'd like to know? I just double click the remote file and am able to read/write. The remote database is in multiuser mode. While "they" work with that db I am able to feed data into its tables.

Comment: That seems unsecured to me (but certainly is curious). I will share 2 alternate approaches with you, probably the first one will work.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to open databases and database connections in Access. You've shared several, but can attempt others too. I'm assuming you're using DAO recordsets to do the inserting.

**Open a database in a separate Access application, and create a reference to the database object**

```
Dim A As New Access.Application
A.OpenCurrentDatabase "X:\path\to\file.accdb"
Dim db As Database
Set db = A.CurrentDb()
```

**Open a recordset on a remote database using the SQL IN statement in the FROM clause**

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset ("SELECT * FROM MyTable IN ""X:\path\to\file.accdb""")
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment and the example provided. However, your use case describes a read process. I have no issues reading from another .accdb file. My Issue relates to writing into another .accdb file while it is currently open and the user who has opend it was not me.

Comment: Well, that's just not true, using both techniques allows both read and write actions  (yes, they are both `SELECT` queries, but you can just as easily use an UPDATE or modify the recordset)

Comment: ... which brings me back to my initial question, 'cuz this just not works for the described reason.

Comment: Then please provide an example in your question with a write action, so I can use it in my answer